# Laravel CSRF token mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have form like this:

```
{{ Form::open([ 'url' => url('programs') ]) }}

{{ csrf_field() }}
```

In controller I am echoing plain all input variables like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

   print_r(Input::all());

   die();
```

I get:

```
Array ( [_token] => leaNP3UN8k3D11AdgWeiSIZYPOUKgSs0fAkiJy8e [cat_id] => 1 [subcat_id] => 13 [degree_type] => MASTERS [pace] => PART_TIME [study_location] => ONLINE [name] => [requirements] => [length] => [price] => [start_date] => [description] => )
```

Which is perfect. I have been checking inputs like this for past 3 laravel applications. But now strange problem happening, when I press f5 it resubmits form. It should again display this same output but instead it shows me csrf mismatch. I have never had this before.

EDIT:

I removed all form fields, just form open csrf_field and form close with a submit button and still I face this problem.

I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: I think `Form::open` already provides a CSRF hidden field, so you don't need to explicitly render one.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi why would it expire in just 1 form submit? when I go back, refresh and submit I get same token.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I have tried without it as well

Comment: As I mentioned, I have used this print_r on all of my past apps

Comment: _token should be a key . why its within [ ] ?

Comment: @unreleased it's the output of `print_r`, not Php.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi doesn't work, just tested

Comment: might be that the sessions are not being stored correctly on the server.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I am working with xampp. I cleared all cookies and relog with the auth as well to test.

Comment: try: php artisan cache:clear .Is the APP_URL correct for your dev/live environment .Try changing 'encrypt' in config/session.php. If that doesn't work:
Chmod 777 storage/framework/sessions might help

Comment: Form::open automatically add csrf token so you don't need to add {{ csrf_field() }} again. After submit it will be validate autometically.

Comment: try 'php artisan config:clear' and 'php artisan config:cache'

Comment: I just don't get it. Nothing is working. I can post any form only once, hitting f5 to resubmit gives csrf mismatch.

Comment: I created a completely new Laravel project, its not working in that either. Is it even possible? or am I hallucinating?